# Comparing and altering values depending on indexes Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, format

I have 3 arrays down below `a` and `b` combine to make `a_and_b`. `a` is multiplied by `a_multiplier` and `b` gets multiplied by `b_multiplier`. I am trying to make a ternary statement where it checks the indexes of `a_and_b` matches with either `a` or `b` then it does the necessary multiplications with `a_multiplier` or `b_multiplier`. How would I be able to modify `a_and_b` ternary function so that the Expected Output works?

```
import numpy as np 

a_multiplier = 3
b_multiplier = 5

a = np.array([5,32,1,4])
b = np.array([1,5,11,3])
a_and_b = np.array([5,1,32,5,1,11,4,3])
a_and_b = a_and_b[::2] * 3,a_and_b[1::2] * 5  if a_and_b[::2] == a 
                        else a_and_b[::2] * 5,a_and_b[1::2] * 3
```

Expected Output:

```
[15, 5, 96, 25, 3, 55, 12, 15]
```

Comment: So a_and_b is basically a and b interleaved?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: So basically the output is a * a_multiplier interleaved with b * b_multiplier?

Comment: Why do you want to do index comparison?

Comment: I want to compare the inside of `a_and_b` because it could start like `[1,5,5,32...]` instead of `[5,1,32,5...]` of where it starts with array `b` instead of array `a`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could do directly:

```
import numpy as np

a_multiplier = 3
b_multiplier = 5

a = np.array([5, 32, 1, 4])
b = np.array([1, 5, 11, 3])

res = np.vstack([a * a_multiplier, b * b_multiplier]).flatten("F")
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[15  5 96 25  3 55 12 15]
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I want to check it with `a_and_b` I tried `a_and_b = np.vstack([a * a_multiplier, b * b_multiplier]).flatten("F")  if a_and_b[::2] == a else np.vstack([b * b_multiplier, a * a_multiplier]).flatten("F")` but that does not work

Comment: I want to do an index comparison first then perform the `np.vstack`